# Accessing Data in MS Graph API Call

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using C# and the Graph Client to access data in the following endpoint.

```
var configAssignments = await graphClient.DeviceManagement.DeviceConfigurations[$"{a.Id}"].Assignments.GetAsync()
```

The response from graph is something like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations('%7B6a58caff-2b72-4fd1-ab9a-609af9e3b619%7D')/assignments",
    "@microsoft.graph.tips": "Use $select to choose only the properties your app needs, as this can lead to performance improvements. For example: GET deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations('<{6a58caff-2b72-4fd1-ab9a-609af9e3b619}>')/assignments?$select=target",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "6a58caff-2b72-4fd1-ab9a-609af9e3b619_2c9626f7-aa6e-4629-84dc-779cd3dc8b89",
            "target": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget",
                "groupId": "2c9626f7-aa6e-4629-84dc-779cd3dc8b89"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "6a58caff-2b72-4fd1-ab9a-609af9e3b619_5a717ea1-f41a-415e-93ca-efcb845b2f99",
            "target": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget",
                "groupId": "5a717ea1-f41a-415e-93ca-efcb845b2f99"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is access the groupId within the target but I'm have trouble doing so. I can access the id just fine though.

```
if (configAssignments.Value != null)
 {
     foreach (var item in configAssignments.Value)
     {
         Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
         assignment.GroupID = item.target.groupId; // doesn't work
         assignment.Id = item.id // does work
         Config.Assignments.Add(assignment);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Put a break point on the line that doesn't work.  The hover on the variable item and check the properties by opening the plus sign.

Comment: @jdweng The project won't build when I use the non working line. I get this error, CS1061 'DeviceAndAppManagementAssignmentTarget' does not contain a definition for 'groupId' and no accessible extension method 'groupId' accepting a first argument of type 'DeviceAndAppManagementAssignmentTarget' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `item.Target` is `GroupAssignmentTarget` and cast `item.Target` to `GroupAssignmentTarget`

```
if (configAssignments.Value != null)
{
    foreach (var item in configAssignments.Value)
    {
        if (item.Target is GroupAssignmentTarget groupAssignment)
        {
            Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
            assignment.GroupID = groupAssignment.GroupId;
            assignment.Id = item.Id;
            Config.Assignments.Add(assignment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!